# GWT. Order of RPC call

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

There is something I can't understand. I have several RPC calls in my GWT code like:

```
private final PravformServiceAsync getPravformService = GWT.create(PravformService.class);
getService.getSome(new AsyncCallback<List<Pravform>>() {
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) { 
  }     
  public void onSuccess(List<Pravform> result) {
    pravformList = result;
  }
});
```

which must executes at the program start. But with help of debugger I saw that code inside these calls doesn't execute at that time. It executes at the end of onModuleLoad() procedure executing, after all other code. It looks like my RPC calls executes on the second circle of code executing.

Please explain me why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what exactly `asyncronous means`,You never know when `server` returns that result to `client`,and mean while the flow continues.That is why people usually write their code in `onSuccess()`,so that futhure execution of flow stops until the request completes.

A clear cut execution and `RPC Plumbing Diagram` is there is Docs.

[Please have a look.](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideRemoteProcedureCalls)

Answer (score 0):

The *Async* in the interface names stands for *asynchronous*. There's a reason you have to make those interfaces taking a callback rather than use the *synchronous* interfaces that just return a value. That reason is they're synchronous, aka *non blocking*.